# How to express combinations mathematically

Tags: notation, combinations

In simple electrical circuits, the total resistance of parallel resistors can be found by

$$\frac{1}{(1/R_1 +1/R_2 +⋯+1/R_n)}$$

Then this can be done with product-over-sum e.g. for two resistors;

$$\frac{R_1R_2}{(R_1 + R_2)}$$

and for three resistors;

$$\frac{R_1R_2R_3}{(R_1R_3 + R_2R_3 + R_1R_2)}$$

And the pattern continues with the numerator simply multiplying all the resistors $R_1R_2R_3...R_n$ and the denominator sum of unique $n-1$ pairs of $R_1R_2R_3...R_n$

The pattern is because:

Since

$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}} = \frac{1}{\frac{R_1+R_2}{R_1R_2}}$$

Then adding another;

$$\frac{1}{\frac{R_1+R_2}{R_1R_2}+\frac{1}{R_3}} = \frac{1}{\frac{R_1R_2+R_1R_3+R_2R_3}{R_1R_2R_3}}$$

There's really nothing special, just that having LCD, reciprocating, thats why every adding of a resistor will have that pattern

So, how do I express this mathematically? I do not know if this is found in other circuit textbooks I just observed the pattern myself and if there is I still want to know how to express things mathematically, I do know simple summation like $\sum_{i=0}^n i^2$, but I'm quite confused with summation of combinations

Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry I dont think there a clear pattern for how the denominator looks.  Can you write maybe the first 6 denominators, or enough that a pattern is clear?

Comment: @NazimJ The pattern is clear: it's just the sum of the products of all the $R_i$ but one.

Comment: These happen to be [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial).  You can borrow notation from that.

Comment: Sorry if I'll take time reading all, I'm really not used to mathematical notations and its already midnight here so maybe I'll accept an answer tomorrow. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The denominator could be written as $\sum_i\prod_{j\ne i}R_j$, viz.$$\frac{1}{\sum_i1/R_i}=\frac{\prod_jR_j}{\sum_i\prod_{j\ne i}R_j}.$$As @JMoravitz notes, one can also write the result as the $k=1$ special case of$$\frac{1}{e_k(1/R_i)}=\frac{e_n(R_i)}{e_{n-k}(R_i)}.$$

Answer (score 2):

You can use cyclic sum notation:

$$\frac{\prod R_i}{\sum_{\textrm{cyc}}R_1R_2\cdots R_{n-1}}$$

Answer (score 2):

If you have $n$ resistances $R_1$, $\dots$, $R_n$, then you have $n$ products of $n-1$ resistances, which you can `label' by which resistance is *not* in the product. So writing the full sum
$$R_2R_3...R_{n} + R_1R_3...R_n + \dots + R_1R_2...R_{n-1}$$
as this:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n R_1...R_{i-1}R_{i+1}...R_n$$
should be clear.

Alternatively, you can use [Pi Product Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Products_of_sequences)
Where $$\prod_{i=1}^n a_i = a_1a_2...a_n$$

Then your sum would be
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{j\neq i}R_i$$
But this is probably a lot less clear to read than the first option.